# "missing ) after argument list error "

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am fairly new to javascript programming and I've been doing this tutorial online. 
I am trying make this function to work but I keep getting "missing ) after argument list". Anyone know what I am doing wrong?

```
$(function() {
    $('#main').append("<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe"/>");

    $('#clickMe').toggle(
        function() {
            $('#message').show('fast');
            $('#clickMe').attr('src', 'minus7.png');
        },
        function() {
            $('#message').hide('slow');
            $('#clickMe').attr('src', 'plus8.png');
        });
    $('message').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is in this line

```
$('#main').append("<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe" />");
```

you cannot nest double quotations inside double quotations, instead mix between double and single quotations for nesting.

```
$('#main').append('<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe" />');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#main').append('<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe"/>');
```

You need to use different types of quotes (double inside single or single inside double) or escape every double quote inside another double quotes, something like this:

```
$('#main').append("<img src=\"plus8.png\" alt=\"Click me to see the paragraph!\" id=\"clickMe\"/>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Your quotes are wrong on your append.

```
$('#main').append("<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe" />");
```

You are continually closing them off by constantly using double quotes, When you open your first double quotes you are closing it off at the "plus8", meaning it starts looking for valid javascript.

Try it like this:

```
$('#main').append('<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe" />');
```

this way the outer single quotes never gets closed off till the end of the append

Answer (score 0):

The error was on the line with `$('#main').append("...")`

You should use simple quotes

```js
$(function() {

  $('#main').append('<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe" />');

  $('#clickMe').toggle(function() {
    $('#message').show('fast');
    $('#clickMe').attr('src', 'minus7.png');


  }, function() {
    $('#message').hide('slow');
    $('#clickMe').attr('src', 'plus8.png');

  });

  $('message').hide();

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#main').append('<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe" />');
```

You can use quotes inside a string, as long as they don't match the quotes surrounding the string:

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

  $('#main').append('<img src="plus8.png" alt="Click me to see the paragraph!" id="clickMe" />');

$('#clickMe').toggle(function() {
$('#message').show('fast');
$('#clickMe').attr('src', 'minus7.png');


  }, function() {
  $('#message').hide('slow');
$('#clickMe').attr('src', 'plus8.png');

});

$('message').hide();

});
```